# AdMob interstitial memory leak? Sprite kit

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, sprite-kit, admob

I have problem with AdMob and sprite kit.

Everytime ad will show or load, it will increase memory usage a lot!
When EndGameScene open it will call "showAd", and when replay button is pressed "loadAd".

Ads works well.

When game starts memory usage is something like 50mb and few ads later it is at least 70-100mb!

So what i do wrong:

GameViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];



[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"showAd" object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"loadAd" object:nil];

self.interstitial = [self createAndLoadInterstitial];
self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:@"ca-app-pub-<id>"];

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
// Requests test ads on test devices.
request.testDevices = @[@"0000000"];
[self.interstitial loadRequest:request];

//etc
}


- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{
if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"showAd"]) {
    if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
        [ self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
    }

    else {

    }

}

if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"loadAd"]) {
   self.interstitial = [self createAndLoadInterstitial];
}
}
- (GADInterstitial *)createAndLoadInterstitial {
GADInterstitial *interstitial =
[[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:@"ca-app-pub-<id>"];
interstitial.delegate = self;
[interstitial loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
return interstitial;}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating everytime a new GADInterstitial object, which starts a load request. I guess because it is waiting for an answer it will never be released from memory again. 
A better way would be to store the GADInterstitial in a global property and just call a new loadRequest, if you need a new ad.